# How to set up email printer driver under IPP?

Tags: email, printing, cups

We're enhancing our software to be able to print to an IPP-based printer (I'm running CUPS on a RedHat-based Linux distro).  The QA person is remote, though, and because of firewalls and proxy servers we cannot configure the IPP-server to use a printer local to him (nor can he set up his own IPP server).  Is there a printer driver I could use or craft that would create a PDF or JPG out of what's sent to it and then turn around and email it to the QA person?  Or is there a better idea for testing this?  Thanks!

Comment: Create a PDF printer; configure it to output to a certian directory; hook inotify, or use a cron job to pickup new files in that directory, email them and delete them.  Not elegant, but probably a 1/2 page of shell scripting...